# Finding the largest even number in a 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some code written down and i can not figure out whats wrong with it since im getting the wrong output.
So i have to find the largest even number in a 2D list and then put that number in a list, if theres no even numbers list should be empty. I am not allowed to use built in python commands, only loops and conditions.

```
def largest_even(matrix):
    listeven = []
    maximum = matrix[0][0]

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) and (matrix[i][j] > maximum):
                maximum = matrix[i][j]
                listeven.append(maximum)
return listeven
```

Testing file:

```
from functions import largest_even

matrix = [[12, 17, 49, 61], [38, 18, 82, 77], [83, 53, 12, 10]]
listeven = largest_even(matrix)
print(listeven)
```

Output: [38,82] where i should be getting [82] only since it is the largest even number

Comment: `listeven.append` *appends* the argument at the end. You instead want to replace it if it is already present

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "built-in commands"? Aren't `range` and `len` [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) / "commands"?

Comment: Well specifically i meant max(), using numpy or lamda

Answer (score 1):

```py
def largest_even(matrix):
    max1=float('-inf')
    for o1 in matrix:
        for o2 in o1:
            if  max1<o2 and o2%2==0:
                max1=o2
    return [] if max1==float('-inf') else [max1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you cant use `max` since it's a built-in function, but here's a nice one-liner for others:

```
max(([val] for row in matrix for val in row if val % 2 == 0), default=[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kindly declare your maximum as a number and not as a 2D matrix form, your code is fine, just change the declaration of maximum (You don't need to declare maximum as a matrix, rather going as a INT will be fine)

```py
   def largest_even(matrix):
    maximum = 0

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if (matrix[i][j] % 2 == 0) and (matrix[i][j] > maximum):
                maximum = matrix[i][j]
    if maximum != 0 return [maximum] else []
```

should work fine :)

And your result will be [82]

Comment: This works but when there are no even numbers the output is [0] which is supposed to be [] so a list is needed in order to get an empty list instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws:

- you assign `matrix[0][0]` as maximum. If this happens to be largest number in 2D matrix then you will have empty `listeven` irrespective of values in matrix.
- every time you find even value what is greater than current maximum you append it to `listeven`

There is no need to access items via indices. Python allows you iterate directly. In order to follow requirements ("find the largest even number in a 2D list and then put that number in a list, if theres no even numbers list should be empty /../ only loops and conditions") and get desired result you can just write:

```
def largest_even_2(matrix):
    max_even = []
    for row in matrix:
        for item in row:
            if item % 2 == 0 and max_even[:1] < [item]:
                max_even = [item]
    return max_even
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for the clarification as well. This works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this loop where you compare with the maximum previous value, initially equal to -infinity.

```py
l = [[12, 17, 49, 61], [38, 18, 82, 77], [83, 53, 12, 10]]
maximum = -float("Inf")
for sublist in l:
     for element in sublist :
             if element % 2 == 0 and maximum < element :
                     maximum = element
```

At the end of the loop, `maximum` will be equal to `82`.

Comment: It's not good idea to use built-in [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) as a variable name

Comment: @AivarPaalberg It's edited now, thank you